# basicPublish wrong routingKey

Tags: rabbitmq

We are actually using basicPublish to produce message on a queue. This works well and having exception thrown if we cannot publish ( broker down, bad exchange name).

Otherwise with an incorrect routingKey, the message is published but not routed. How can i get this information that the message is lost (neither in a dead letter queue)?

Adding a confirmlistener on the channel indicates that the message is acked.
We also use alternate exchange with no results.

Following our code :

```
channel.addConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {

    @Override
    public void handleNack(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("*****handleNack , deliveryTag ["+deliveryTag+"], mulitple ["+multiple+"]");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleAck(long deliveryTag, boolean multiple)
            throws IOException {

        System.out.println("handleAck, deliveryTag ["+deliveryTag+"], mulitple ["+multiple+"]");

    }
});
channel.basicPublish(exchangeName, routing_key, false, false, bp,message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Thanks and Regards,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Following solution on my requirement (adding a ReturnListener on the channel  and change arguments on the basicPublish : mandatory to true)

```
channel.addReturnListener(new ReturnListener() {
    public void handleReturn(int replyCode, String replyText,
            String exchange, String routingKey,
            AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
            throws IOException {
        String str_successflag = "false";
        String detailMsg = "Could not publish the message using exchange:"
                + exchange
                + " "
                + "and "
                + "routing key:"
                + routingKey;

        System.out.println(detailMsg);
    }
});   
channel.basicPublish(exchangeName, routing_key, true, false, bp,message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

If the routing is wrong then the handleReturn method is called.